# How to get a dict of the keys for all values in another dict

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

I am trying to iterate over a dictionary with multiple values for same index to account for repeating values.

```
a = []
for x,y in new2.items():
    a[y].append(x)
print(a)
```

I have tried many approaches please help me identify the possible error.

The input file is like: `{0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 6, ...}`

The output should be: `{1: [0, 1], 2: [2, 3, 4], 6: [5, 6, 7], 7: [8, 9], 12: [10], 14: [11, 12], 15: [15, 16]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have to initialize `a` to a `defaultdict`, not to a list

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> new2 = {'caseid': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 6}}
>>> a = defaultdict(list)
>>> for x,y in new2['caseid'].items():
...     a[y].append(x)
... 
>>> print(a)
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: [0, 1], 2: [2, 3, 4], 6: [5]})
>>> print(dict(a))
{1: [0, 1], 2: [2, 3, 4], 6: [5]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there's a nested `dict` to parse values from:

```
new_d = {'caseid1': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 6},
         'caseid2': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 6},
         'caseid3': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 6},
         'caseid4': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 6},
         'caseid5': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 6},
         'caseid6': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 6}}

a = defaultdict(list)

for k1, v1 in new_d.items():
    for k2, v2 in v1.items():
        a[f'{k1}_{v2}'].append(k2)

# print(a)        
defaultdict(list,
            {'caseid1_1': [0, 1],
             'caseid1_2': [2, 3, 4],
             'caseid1_6': [5],
             'caseid2_1': [0, 1],
             'caseid2_2': [2, 3, 4],
             'caseid2_6': [5],
             'caseid3_1': [0, 1],
             'caseid3_2': [2, 3, 4],
             'caseid3_6': [5],
             'caseid4_1': [0, 1],
             'caseid4_2': [2, 3, 4],
             'caseid4_6': [5],
             'caseid5_1': [0, 1],
             'caseid5_2': [2, 3, 4],
             'caseid5_6': [5],
             'caseid6_1': [0, 1],
             'caseid6_2': [2, 3, 4],
             'caseid6_6': [5]})
```